# Select only one column even if a merged range lies below

Tags: vba, excel

**Test case:**

Take an empty sheet, and merge the range `"D2:F2"`. You can do this manually.

Then, activate the macro recorder and select the column `E` by just clicking on the `E` letter on the top of the spreadsheet. You will get the following:

```
Columns("E:E").Select
```

Now, try to run this line of code from the same macro directly: you will see that it selects the three columns `D, E` and `F`.

**Question:**

Is this a bug of the macro recorder? Or, rather, a bug of VBA itself (that detects the merged range in my column and decides to extend the selection even if explicitly asked to select one single column)? How should I do to select *only one of the columns on which a merged range lies* via VBA code, exactly as I can do manually?

**Need:**

I have a spreadsheet with year on a line, months on the below line and days on the below line. 
Hence, the days are  just cells but months and especially years are shared/merged cells among the several days.

My need is just to detect the current day and select the column, in order for the user to see on which day they should look the data at. But, because of the "years" cell widely merged just above, the entire year is selected. [image]

Comment: I think it's just a feature of how `.Select` mimics user behaviour. For example, `Columns("E:E").Value = 1` would do exactly as you expect here.

Comment: @CallumDA the problem is that this is not the user behaviour. If the user selects column E, only column E is selected. This is why I was rather thinking to a bug of the Select method, or most probably just to me not knowing how to do that.

Comment: its most likely because excel treats merged cells as a single object.

Comment: By "detect the current day"... how exactly do you intend to show the user which day to look at?

Comment: @CallumDA, it's just about selecting "today". The plan contains a lot of working days, I just want to select the current one by highlighting the respective column (without using any formatting, if possible).

Comment: That is exactly my question. How are you going to "highlight" the respective column without using formatting?

Comment: Since one column = 1 day, I wanted just to highlight the column.

Comment: @CallumDA I have added a picture to my question, maybe it helps you to understand what I mean,

Comment: You plan to use `.Select` to get the user to the right column?

Comment: @CallumDA, exactly, you got it right. There's a little button "bring me to today", the user clicks it and he falls on the wished column.

Comment: This is a very valid question. Here's why. When I select a range which includes a merged portion in the worksheet manually, the selection extends to the whole merged portion. So additional columns will be included to the column I was trying to select when I select the range using mouse or keyboard shortcut SHIFT/CTRL+SPACE. However, if I click on the Column Header (say column E then press on that "E"), then it only selects the column E ignoring all the merged portions. That is exactly what I'd expect VBA to do when I tell it to select a column instead of a range. So, let us find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably know the row in which the days start. Therefore, instead of selecting the entire column, you could define a range starting from the first day row to the last day row and select that range.

Comment: That's the solution I had thought about already, I didn't like it 100% but if it's the only one I'll accept your answer and also accept the VBA limitation/feature.

Comment: If you wish to accept an answer you should click on the green checkmark below the votes. Frankly, I don't think my answer is worth that much, but let me know if you need any help with the coding.

Comment: I know, I've been around in this site for a long while :) I didn't accept it yet just to wait if someone has an answer better fitting my needs. But if not by the end of the day, I'll do that!

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not a bug.

Why: Try to manually select the range E1 to E5. That is what is going on when you use Columns("E:E").select. Think of it as .Select not selecting the column, but instead selecting each cell from top to bottom.

The .select method isn't something you should depend on. What exactly are you trying to use select for? There is another (quite arguably better way) to do this.

Edit: Also, as my father always says, merged cells shouldn't be used. He uses "center across selection" instead, which looks exactly like a merged cell without any of the seemingly buggy behavior.

Need: I would use the macro to highlight the data... probably with something like this...

`Range("E7").Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Added a "need" part to my question. I agree with your father, but I hadn't followed his suggestions when started to develop the spreadsheet and now it's way too late to change the architecture :(

Comment: Updated with an answer to your need :)

Comment: Thanks, honestly thinking I have already thought not to use that solution. It's nice itself, but my spreadsheet is a big bunch of colors flashing everywhere, managing format cleaning/rebuilding is already complicated so I would have just selected the column instead of adding further formatting.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that the question is genuine unlike some of the comments here. I will try to explain.

Using the test case from the question, say I want to do some action only on column D (say change its column width), without changing the same for columns E to F. I can do that in excel by selecting column D specifically by pressing on column header (press on that "D" in the column names bar). If we select column using range selection (mouse or keyboard shortcut CTRL+SPACE), it extends the selection to include E and F columns. But if we press that column D on the header, it only selects one column. I expect VBA to do the same.

Sadly, I couldn't find anything to "select" a single column or range which includes cells merging through multiple columns or range. However, I could do the action on that single column.

I tried following that didn't work. And I feel that it should work.

```
Range("D:D").Select
```

Didn't work. Extends the selection to include merged cells. I guess, this is okay.

```
Columns("D").Select
```

Didn't work. Extends the selection to include merged cells. I feel this is not okay.

```
Columns("D").EntireColumn.Select
```

Even this didn't work. This definitely should've.

So finally I directly applied the action without selecting the cells.

```
Column("D").ColumnWidth = 10
```

And this did it. Only the column D width was changed, leaving column E and F untouched. Similarly, I could do font change and other actions.

Only drawback is that I have to do all actions individually. So, I use a loop to perform action on the selection.

Something like this:

```
For Each x in Range("D:D")
    x.font.size = 10
    x.font.name = "Calibri"
    '...and so on...
Next x
```

Answer (score 1):

**REQUIREMENTS:**

Your table should have this values and formats

[image: sample picture]

Then you can loop through each column on row 4 -just assumed- and check each value if they match today. Next you can scroll to that cell using `Application.Goto`.

**CODE:**

```
Sub FindToday()
  Dim wsTable As Worksheet  '<~ worksheet with your table
  Set wsTable = Sheet2
  Dim Cols As Integer       '<~ a variable to loop through columns
  With wsTable
    For Cols = 1 To .Cells(4, .Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
      If .Cells(4, Cols).Value = Date Then  '<~ check if the date is today
      Application.Goto wsTable.Cells(1, Cols), True '<~ scroll to that cell if true
      Exit For
      End If
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Romcel, that's pretty much what I ended up doing with!

Comment: It is great to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to hide the particular column if there is merged cell try not to select the column just use like this for example -- `Columns("N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`... This will solve your doubt.